# PDE toolbox function decsg is extremely slow

Tags: matlab, pde

I am trying to solve a 2d diffusion equation in Matlab. My geometry is a 2d grid (1500X750 size) of ones and zeros, where the ones indicates a source (global ProMat in the code is a matrix of 1500X750).

Right now I am using the Matlab Partial Differential Equation (PDE) toolbox and the simulation is extremely slow. The problem seems to be in the `decsg()` function used to create the geometry. I would like to make it more efficient.

```matlab
% Set the coefficients in a 3-D rectangular block geometry.
N1=size(ProMat,1);
N2=size(ProMat,2);
model = createpde();
R1 = [3 4 0 0 N1 N1 0 N2 N2 0]';
nm(1:2,1)='R1';

% The problem is here
g = decsg(R1,'R1',nm);
geometryFromEdges(model,g);
%fff = @(region,state)(region.x.^2);
```